# Windows guest in VMware Fusion not able to see Mac's internet connection

Tags: windows, macos, vmware-fusion

My VMware Fusion Windows VM can't access the internet.

I had to swap a MacBook Pro's HDD to another MacBook Pro. The Mac is the host and the Windows 7 VM reports Ethernet cable not being plugged in; but I can access Internet from the host Mac fine. I'm using the *Share the Mac's network connection* setting (NAT).

I tried all the troubleshooting steps on [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016466) with no luck.